# Where was Hamura when Madara decided to steal the Ten-Tails' Gedo Body?

Tags: naruto

The main reason Hamura and his family went to the moon was to watch over the Ten-Tails' outer body. So, how was Madara able to steal the Ten-Tails' outer body so easily? It seems like a plot crack because the Otsutsuki would have been protecting it, right?

Comment: I believe Hamura was already dead way past that time when Madara summoned the Juubi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that Homura Otsusuki went over to the moon to watch over the Juubi's husk (Ten-Tails' Gedo Body) but then, he most definitely died around the same time that his [elder brother did](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hamura_%C5%8Ctsutsuki), and that was long before Madara's time.

In [The Last: Naruto the Movie](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last:_Naruto_the_Movie), Toneri Otsutsuki spoke about this when he told the [story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fyPGjowdUk)  of the clan to Hinata.

> Apparently, the Otsutsuki Clan that followed Homura to the moon died out and [Toneri Otsutsuki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Toneri_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) became the last surviving member of the Otsutsuki branch family, which explains a lot actually.

By the time Madara attained the Rinnegan and decided to summon the Husk of the Juubi, the majority of the Otsutsuki Clan on the moon, along with Hamura Otsutsuki, had died off. So, it was not being guarded at that time and Madara could easily just summon it.

Comment: How are you sure the timeline is the same as during that time

Comment: because we know that toneri Otutsuki's dad died and left him as the lone survivor in the Naruto the last movie and that timeline would probably fit in to  around a couple years before the 4th great Ninja war. Or probably around that timeline i think